Как запустить программу от имени svchost.exe
Пытаюсь запустить программу (Minecraft.Windows.exe) через папку или консоль, выдаётся ошибка "Не удаётся продолжить выполнение кода поскольку система не обнаружила (Библеотека.dll). Для устранения этой проблемы попробуйте переустановить программу." При этом если я попытаюсь зайти в него через лаунчер или xbox, он спокойно открывается без ошибок.
Через process hacker я узнал что если я открываю exe через консоль или проводник его родительский процесс становится explorer.exe, ну а если через лаунчер то svchost.exe Можно ли открыть программу от svchost.exe чтобы программа получала из него нужные библеотеки? Если да то как это сделать? (если можно то код на языке програмирования java,c++,c# или похожие)

я бы взял Process Explorer и глянул бы полный CMD запрос процесса(путь к exe"шнику с добавленными к нему флагами) запущенного svchost'ом. к примеру адрес защитника на 7ке выглядит так C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k secsvcs а службы wia так C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k imgsvc. сам же svchost без флагов, возможно и не запустится вовсе.
